# How to make a scrollview which could scroll to all directions with a acceleration?

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

The original scrollview provided by Corona SDK only support vertical and horizontal scrolling, but it can't do it both in the same time.

As you can see, the video blow did that. But it is not free. So how can I do it?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=ecAcUxex46c#t=74

Thank you very much.

Comment: set mask and drag option to the object.Drag should be in limit.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example, you can use a picture instead of rectangle I put:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

 local sceneGroup = display.newGroup();

-- Create scene
  local ox, oy = math.abs(display.screenOriginX), math.abs(display.screenOriginY)
  local tabBarHeight = 25

  -- Adjust background color for some themes
  local backgroundColor = { 240/255 }


  -- scrollView listener
  local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    local direction = event.direction

    if "began" == phase then
      --print( "Began" )
    elseif "moved" == phase then
      --print( "Moved" )
    elseif "ended" == phase then
      --print( "Ended" )
    end

    -- If the scrollView has reached its scroll limit
    if event.limitReached then
      if "up" == direction then
        --print( "Reached Top Limit" )
      elseif "down" == direction then
        --print( "Reached Bottom Limit" )
      elseif "left" == direction then
        --print( "Reached Left Limit" )
      elseif "right" == direction then
        --print( "Reached Right Limit" )
      end
    end

    return true
  end

  -- Create a scrollView
  local scrollView = widget.newScrollView {
    left = 20-ox,
    top = 62,
    width = display.contentWidth+ox+ox-60,
    height = display.contentHeight-32-tabBarHeight-120,
    hideBackground = false,
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    --isBounceEnabled = false,
    horizontalScrollingDisabled = false,
    verticalScrollingDisabled = false,
    listener = scrollListener
  }
  sceneGroup:insert( scrollView )

  -- Insert an image into the scrollView
  local background = display.newRect( 100, 100, 1200, 1200 )
  background.x = background.contentWidth * 0.5
  background.y = background.contentHeight * 0.5
  scrollView:insert( background )

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Insert various other widgets into scrollView to exhibit functionality
  -------------------------------------------------------------------------

  -- Radio button set
  local radioGroup = display.newGroup()
  local radioButton = widget.newSwitch {
    left = 20,
    style = "radio",
    initialSwitchState = true
  }
  radioGroup:insert( radioButton )
  radioButton.y = 50

  local radioButton2 = widget.newSwitch {
    style = "radio"
  }
  radioGroup:insert( radioButton2 )
  radioButton2.x = radioButton.x+radioButton.width
  radioButton2.y = 50
  scrollView:insert( radioGroup )

  -- Checkbox
  local checkboxButton = widget.newSwitch {
    style = "checkbox"
  }
  checkboxButton.x = radioButton2.x+radioButton2.width+20
  checkboxButton.y = 50
  scrollView:insert( checkboxButton )

  -- On/off switch
  local onOffSwitch = widget.newSwitch {
    style = "onOff",
    initialSwitchState = false
  }
  onOffSwitch.y = 50
  scrollView:insert( onOffSwitch )

  -- Stepper
  local stepper = widget.newStepper {
    left = 20,
    top = 80,
    initialValue = 4,
    minimumValue = 0,
    maximumValue = 25
  }
  scrollView:insert( stepper )

  -- Progress view
  local progressView = widget.newProgressView {
    left = 130,
    width = 125,
    isAnimated = true,
  }
  scrollView:insert( progressView )
  progressView.y = stepper.y
  local currentProgress = 0.0
  testTimer = timer.performWithDelay( 100, function( event )
    currentProgress = currentProgress + 0.01
    progressView:setProgress( currentProgress )
  end, 50 )

  onOffSwitch.x = progressView.x+12
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I used your code, it can't scrolling oblique, it can either vertical scrolling or horizontal scrolling. You can check more detail in the video i post above.

Comment: You said two directions. Accept that as an answer and I'll send you the oblique one.

Comment: I added another one which you can use to drag and zoom. I have to add the scroll bar when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

The drag and zoom option in all direction:

```
-- turn on multitouch
system.activate("multitouch")

-- which environment are we running on?
local isDevice = (system.getInfo("environment") == "device")



-- returns the distance between points a and b
function lengthOf( a, b )
    local width, height = b.x-a.x, b.y-a.y
    return (width*width + height*height)^0.5
end

-- returns the degrees between (0,0) and pt
-- note: 0 degrees is 'east'
function angleOfPoint( pt )
    local x, y = pt.x, pt.y
    local radian = math.atan2(y,x)
    local angle = radian*180/math.pi
    if angle < 0 then angle = 360 + angle end
    return angle
end

-- returns the degrees between two points
-- note: 0 degrees is 'east'
function angleBetweenPoints( a, b )
    local x, y = b.x - a.x, b.y - a.y
    return angleOfPoint( { x=x, y=y } )
end

-- returns the smallest angle between the two angles
-- ie: the difference between the two angles via the shortest distance
function smallestAngleDiff( target, source )
    local a = target - source

    if (a > 180) then
        a = a - 360
    elseif (a < -180) then
        a = a + 360
    end

    return a
end

-- rotates a point around the (0,0) point by degrees
-- returns new point object
function rotatePoint( point, degrees )
    local x, y = point.x, point.y

    local theta = math.rad( degrees )

    local pt = {
        x = x * math.cos(theta) - y * math.sin(theta),
        y = x * math.sin(theta) + y * math.cos(theta)
    }

    return pt
end

-- rotates point around the centre by degrees
-- rounds the returned coordinates using math.round() if round == true
-- returns new coordinates object
function rotateAboutPoint( point, centre, degrees, round )
    local pt = { x=point.x - centre.x, y=point.y - centre.y }
    pt = rotatePoint( pt, degrees )
    pt.x, pt.y = pt.x + centre.x, pt.y + centre.y
    if (round) then
        pt.x = math.round(pt.x)
        pt.y = math.round(pt.y)
    end
    return pt
end



-- calculates the average centre of a list of points
local function calcAvgCentre( points )
    local x, y = 0, 0

    for i=1, #points do
        local pt = points[i]
        x = x + pt.x
        y = y + pt.y
    end

    return { x = x / #points, y = y / #points }
end

-- calculate each tracking dot's distance and angle from the midpoint
local function updateTracking( centre, points )
    for i=1, #points do
        local point = points[i]

        point.prevAngle = point.angle
        point.prevDistance = point.distance

        point.angle = angleBetweenPoints( centre, point )
        point.distance = lengthOf( centre, point )
    end
end

-- calculates rotation amount based on the average change in tracking point rotation
local function calcAverageRotation( points )
    local total = 0

    for i=1, #points do
        local point = points[i]
        total = total + smallestAngleDiff( point.angle, point.prevAngle )
    end

    return total / #points
end

-- calculates scaling amount based on the average change in tracking point distances
local function calcAverageScaling( points )
    local total = 0

    for i=1, #points do
        local point = points[i]
        total = total + point.distance / point.prevDistance
    end

    return total / #points
end



-- creates an object to be moved
function newTrackDot(e)
    -- create a user interface object
    local circle = display.newCircle( e.x, e.y, 50 )

    -- make it less imposing
    circle.alpha = .5

    -- keep reference to the rectangle
    local rect = e.target

    -- standard multi-touch event listener
    function circle:touch(e)
        -- get the object which received the touch event
        local target = circle

        -- store the parent object in the event
        e.parent = rect

        -- handle each phase of the touch event life cycle...
        if (e.phase == "began") then
            -- tell corona that following touches come to this display object
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(target, e.id)
            -- remember that this object has the focus
            target.hasFocus = true
            -- indicate the event was handled
            return true
        elseif (target.hasFocus) then
            -- this object is handling touches
            if (e.phase == "moved") then
                -- move the display object with the touch (or whatever)
                target.x, target.y = e.x, e.y
            else -- "ended" and "cancelled" phases
                -- stop being responsible for touches
                display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(target, nil)
                -- remember this object no longer has the focus
                target.hasFocus = false
            end

            -- send the event parameter to the rect object
            rect:touch(e)

            -- indicate that we handled the touch and not to propagate it
            return true
        end

        -- if the target is not responsible for this touch event return false
        return false
    end

    -- listen for touches starting on the touch layer
    circle:addEventListener("touch")

    -- listen for a tap when running in the simulator
    function circle:tap(e)
        if (e.numTaps == 2) then
            -- set the parent
            e.parent = rect

            -- call touch to remove the tracking dot
            rect:touch(e)
        end
        return true
    end

    -- only attach tap listener in the simulator
    if (not isDevice) then
        circle:addEventListener("tap")
    end

    -- pass the began phase to the tracking dot
    circle:touch(e)

    -- return the object for use
    return circle
end



-- spawning tracking dots

-- create display group to listen for new touches
local group = display.newGroup()

-- populate display group with objects
local rect = display.newRect( group, 200, 200, 200, 100 )
rect:setFillColor(0,0,255)

rect = display.newRect( group, 300, 300, 200, 100 )
rect:setFillColor(0,255,0)

rect = display.newRect( group, 100, 400, 200, 100 )
rect:setFillColor(255,0,0)

-- keep a list of the tracking dots
group.dots = {}

-- advanced multi-touch event listener
function touch(self, e)
    -- get the object which received the touch event
    local target = e.target

    -- get reference to self object
    local rect = self

    -- handle began phase of the touch event life cycle...
    if (e.phase == "began") then
        print( e.phase, e.x, e.y )

        -- create a tracking dot
        local dot = newTrackDot(e)

        -- add the new dot to the list
        rect.dots[ #rect.dots+1 ] = dot

        -- pre-store the average centre position of all touch points
        rect.prevCentre = calcAvgCentre( rect.dots )

        -- pre-store the tracking dot scale and rotation values
        updateTracking( rect.prevCentre, rect.dots )

        -- we handled the began phase
        return true
    elseif (e.parent == rect) then
        if (e.phase == "moved") then
            print( e.phase, e.x, e.y )

            -- declare working variables
            local centre, scale, rotate = {}, 1, 0

            -- calculate the average centre position of all touch points
            centre = calcAvgCentre( rect.dots )

            -- refresh tracking dot scale and rotation values
            updateTracking( rect.prevCentre, rect.dots )

            -- if there is more than one tracking dot, calculate the rotation and scaling
            if (#rect.dots > 1) then
                -- calculate the average rotation of the tracking dots
                rotate = calcAverageRotation( rect.dots )

                -- calculate the average scaling of the tracking dots
                scale = calcAverageScaling( rect.dots )

                -- apply rotation to rect
                rect.rotation = rect.rotation + rotate

                -- apply scaling to rect
                rect.xScale, rect.yScale = rect.xScale * scale, rect.yScale * scale
            end

            -- declare working point for the rect location
            local pt = {}

            -- translation relative to centre point move
            pt.x = rect.x + (centre.x - rect.prevCentre.x)
            pt.y = rect.y + (centre.y - rect.prevCentre.y)

            -- scale around the average centre of the pinch
            -- (centre of the tracking dots, not the rect centre)
            pt.x = centre.x + ((pt.x - centre.x) * scale)
            pt.y = centre.y + ((pt.y - centre.y) * scale)

            -- rotate the rect centre around the pinch centre
            -- (same rotation as the rect is rotated!)
            pt = rotateAboutPoint( pt, centre, rotate, false )

            -- apply pinch translation, scaling and rotation to the rect centre
            rect.x, rect.y = pt.x, pt.y

            -- store the centre of all touch points
            rect.prevCentre = centre
        else -- "ended" and "cancelled" phases
            print( e.phase, e.x, e.y )

            -- remove the tracking dot from the list
            if (isDevice or e.numTaps == 2) then
                -- get index of dot to be removed
                local index = table.indexOf( rect.dots, e.target )

                -- remove dot from list
                table.remove( rect.dots, index )

                -- remove tracking dot from the screen
                e.target:removeSelf()

                -- store the new centre of all touch points
                rect.prevCentre = calcAvgCentre( rect.dots )

                -- refresh tracking dot scale and rotation values
                updateTracking( rect.prevCentre, rect.dots )
            end
        end
        return true
    end

    -- if the target is not responsible for this touch event return false
    return false
end

-- attach pinch zoom touch listener
group.touch = touch

-- listen for touches starting on the touch object
group:addEventListener("touch")
```